# Struggling extracting columns data from csv file in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following csv file where I want to plot each column(temp, current and voltage):

```
Date/Time:         01/03/2021 11.15.10
Parameter [s]:     6
Time [sec]:        30

Temp[C]    Cur[A]       Volt[V]
-------     -------     -------
-0,022468   0,00        0,00
-0,022481   0,00        0,00
-0,022582   0,00        0,00
-0,021734   0,00        0,00
-0,022541   0,00        0,00
-0,022658   0,00        0,00
-0,022723   0,00        0,00
-0,022253   0,00        0,00
-0,022048   0,00        0,00
-0,022066   0,00        0,00
-0,023073   0,00        0,00
```

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\myFile.csv', delimiter="/t", decimal=",")
```

But very confused since my file as you see has 3 columns with one tab between col1 and and col 2 and two tabs between col2 and col3. The file has also header first 6 lines.

How can this be done using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `read_csv` with `skiprows` parameter and set '-------' as `na_values`, so it can be easily dropped with `dropna` later:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s+', decimal=',',
                 skiprows=4, na_values='-------')

df = df.dropna()
df.plot()
```

Output:

[image: picture]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also tell me how can we plot only one particular column? df[1] or df(1) doesnt work

Comment: @user1999 For plotting a column by name you can use `loc` for plotting a column by name or `iloc` for plotting it by number: `df.loc[:, col_name].plot()` or `df.iloc[:, col_number].plot()`